# a function that is constant almost everywhere and continuous on its boundary points

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let us consider a measurable function $f$ defined over $[0,1]$. We assume that $f$ is right continuous at $0$ and left continuous at $1$ and $f$ is constant almost everywhere i.e.

$$
f(t) = c,
$$
for a.e. $t\in [0,1]$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

From the left and right continuity of $f$ at $0$ and $1$ can we deduce that
$$ f(0)= f(1) = c$$
holds true ?

Comment: Hint: the set $\{0\le x\le 1\,:\, f(x)=c\}$ is dense in $[0,1].$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc So it is sufficient to take a sequence of this set converging to $0$ and then apply $f$ to it ?

Comment: Yes. The same at $x=1.$